# How do I fill values in vectors in R?

Tags: r

So I need to create a vector V and fill them with the values based on the vector temp
if temp[I] > 100 then fill vi with the string hot else fill with normal

my code is like that

```
for (I in temp) {
if (temp[I] > 100) {
V[I]="Hot"}
else {
V[I] = "Normal 
}
```

but I cannot get the answer what is wrong w my code?

Comment: `I` iterates over the vector elements, `I` is not a sequence of index values.

Comment: w@user2974951 how should I change my code

Comment: R is vectorised by default.  You don't need a loop to do this.  Take a look at the online doc for `ifelse` and you'll be able to do what you want in one line.

Comment: @Limey How do I do so

Comment: Just use `ifelse()`

Comment: if else(temp, "Hot","Normal")?

Comment: How do you read the online doc?  Type `?ifelse` at the console.

Comment: @Limey I have no console only an IDE, I am using hacker ranker

Comment: @max Use this: `ifelse(temp, "Hot", "Normal")` and pass it to the variable to return through the function.

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

temp %>% 
  mutate(v = case_when(i > 100 ~ "hot",
                       TRUE ~ "normal"))
```

Comment: Is tidyverse really necessary?

Comment: No, it's just one solution. There are many other ways to do this.

Comment: how to use ifellse?